# Merge columns with identical values in a smart table (responsive table)

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Is it possible to merge duplicates in a sapui5 smart table?

In a smarttable (with a responsive table) we are grouping values by supplier and would like to merge duplicated values into one cell to get a better readability of the responsive table. 
Outside of Fiori elements (smarttable) this can be done in the column definition in XML using mergeDuplicates: true.

Comment: maybe the grouping functinality is already a good starter

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible to merge duplicates via SAP UI5 Visual Editor, the properties of controls are available there.

> Not all properties are subject to change. Only properties that have been enabled for editing may be changed.

Best,
Shanir

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give me some more details? I am on a smarttable and I can not find any column related properties in the visual editor. I was rather thinking about some annotation, but could not find the right one yet.